# breakpoints using bourbon neat grid

Tags: frameworks, sass, media-queries, mixins, bourbon

I am trying to use neat for bourbon and I have got most things sorted out but I am hitting some road blocks when it comes to creating the breaking points.

I prefer to make seperate sass files for mobile, tablet, desktop & largedesktop and I don't normally use bubbling to create my media queries as I dont like how it doesn't just create one the media query it makes tones through out the css file. But so far I can only seem to find documentation on a bubbling method.

[Article on how to use breakpoints in neat](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/34653032294/version-1-0-of-bourbon-neat-a-sass-based-responsive)

Here is what I have done:

```
$largedesktop-size:em(1050);

    // Bourbon Neat Breakpoints
    $largedesktop: new-breakpoint(min-width $largedesktop-size 16);


 @include media($largedesktop) { 
    body{
        background:black;
    }
  }
```

I have also tried this, which does update the bg color but doesn't update the visual grid:

```
// Media Queries Breakpoints
$tablet-size:em(700);

@include media(min-width $tablet-size 8) {
    body{
        background:orange;
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you fix my problem here is the link
**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721937/website-not-displaying-properly-on-devices-but-does-ok-on-browser**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I actually figured this one out, my main problem was just with how I had organised my .scss files but here is how.

File structure like this:

```
@import 'bourbon/bourbon';
@import 'variables';
@import 'neat/neat';

@import 'base';

// Media Queries
@import 'mobile';
@import 'tablet';
@import 'desktop';
@import 'largedesktop';
```

Variables must go before importing variables.

in _variables.scss add your queries like so:

```
$mobile-size:em(320);
$tablet-size:720px;
$desktop-size:em(960);
$largedesktop-size:em(1050);

// Bourbon Neat Breakpoints
$mobile: new-breakpoint(min-width $mobile-size 4);
$tablet: new-breakpoint(min-width $tablet-size 8);
$desktop: new-breakpoint(min-width $desktop-size 12);
$largedesktop: new-breakpoint(min-width $largedesktop-size 16);
```

Then (this is how I like to organise things) create a scss file for mobile, tablet, desktop & largedesktop and import after _base.scss – I have illustrated above how the files should be structured.

Inside each add your media query along with the needed layout changes.

like this:
_mobile.scss

```
@include media($mobile) {
    body {
        background: purple;
    }
}
```

That should work for you.

As I said this is how I did it, I am sure there are many others but I wanted to let people know one way if they are having problems :)

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem with the breakpoints and with updating the grid. Slightly different track, though ...

Here is what helped me. This is *not* in the [main documentation](http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/).

On the Neat [GitHub page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat#using-neat), the thoughtbot team explains:

1. You need to create a _grid-settings.scss file
2. import it right before importing Neat

   ```
   @import "bourbon/bourbon"; // or "bourbon" when in Rails
   @import "grid-settings";
   @import "neat/neat"; // or "neat" when in Rails
   ```
3. In the _grid-settings.scss file, import neat-helpers

   ```
   @import "neat/neat-helpers"; // or "neat-helpers" when in Rails

   // Define your breakpoints
   $tablet: new-breakpoint(max-width 768px 8);
   $mobile: new-breakpoint(max-width 480px 4);
   etc
   ```

Prior to adding this setup, I could *see* the grid, but the grid would not respond to my breakpoint requests to update columns or change component position. Once I had these settings in place, the grid worked as I expected.

I am using CodeKit 2, if that matters.

Comment: Surely this should be the accepted answer - that neat-helpers file is pretty important

Answer (score 2):

To whoever it may concern, my problem was not that I had the wrong order of imports, but how I used my variables. I thought the function took a string...

This is wrong:

```
$desktop: 1200px
$tablet: new-breakpoint(min-width 600px max-width #{$desktop})
```

This is correct:

```
$desktop: 1200px
$tablet: new-breakpoint(min-width 600px max-width $desktop)
```